# How to store and manage tokens in Client Credential Flow between APIs?

Tags: c#, api, authentication, .net-core, jwt

I don't know how to implement the client part of the [Client Credential Flow](https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/access-tokens/client-credentials/) for two APIs.

Scenario:
An API A obtains a JWT token (your own token) from an identity server ([keycloak](https://www.keycloak.org/)) to access an API B.

Technology: .NET Core with C #

How to store the token in API A to be used in requests for API B?
How to manage token expiration so that it is refreshed?

Is it a good option to use a singleton instance of a class that stores the token and uses a Timer to refresh the token?
Is it better to have a worker service (background) to manage token expiration?

Are there other ways to store and manage token expiration in this scenario?

Is possible to use [`IdentityModel`](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#creating-the-client) with keycloak?

Comment: does API A only have one token or one per user?

Comment: The API A have only one token.

Comment: Yes, you can store the token in a singleton. Just take care of thread safety. Regarding your API calls, use `services.AddHttpClient<YourAClient>((serviceProvider, httpClient) => {})`

Comment: And how to do for manage expiration? A timer to refresh the token before expiration is good idea?

Comment: I don't see any official concept for this. You would have to have a reused code that checks if your response is 401. If 401, you can request a refresh token and set header

Comment: Do you have any tips on how to implement this? Perhaps a class responsible for centralizing requests and monitoring 401 responses? A 401 response is not necessarily due to an expired token, so I have to manage that as well (a second 401 response from the same request shouldn't attempt to refresh the token), right?

Comment: just added a sample code in answers

Answer (score 1):

You can use a singleton similar to this:

```
public class TokenStore
{

    public string Token { get; set; }

    public string RefreshToken { get; set; }

}
```

Next, you can create a `System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler` to take care of the whole Token process. It would be something like this:

```
public class MyTokenHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    private readonly TokenStore _tokenStore;

    private TaskCompletionSource<object> updateTokenTaskCompletionSource;

    public MyTokenHandler(TokenStore tokenStore)
    {
        _tokenStore = tokenStore;
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    { 

        // check if token is already being fetched
        if (updateTokenTaskCompletionSource != null)
            await updateTokenTaskCompletionSource.Task;

        var httpResponse = await InternalSendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
        // you can add conditions such as excluding Paths and checking response message to avoid recursion
        // you can also verify token expiary based on time
        {
            // intentionally not passing in the refresh token
            // at this point we know there is an expired token. So, we can update token regardless of the main request being cancelled
            await UpdateTokenAsync();
            httpResponse = await InternalSendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        }

        return httpResponse;
    }

    private async Task UpdateTokenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        // taskCompletionSource handles multiple requests attempting to refresh token at the same time 
        if (updateTokenTaskCompletionSource is null)
        {
            updateTokenTaskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<object>();
            try
            {
                var refreshRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/token");
                var refreshResponse = await base.SendAsync(refreshRequest, cancellationToken);

                _tokenStore.Token = "updated token here";
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                updateTokenTaskCompletionSource.TrySetException(e);
                updateTokenTaskCompletionSource = null;
                throw new Exception("Failed fetching token", e);
            }

            updateTokenTaskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(null);
            updateTokenTaskCompletionSource = null;
        }
        else
            await updateTokenTaskCompletionSource.Task;
    }

    private async Task<HttpResponseMessage> InternalSendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", _tokenStore.Token);
        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
    

}
```

Finally, in your startup.cs you can add this code:

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyClientService>(httpClient =>
{
    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri("Your base URL");
}).AddHttpMessageHandler<MyTokenHandler>();
```

Note that I haven't accounted for setting the `RefreshToken`. You can set it based on the requirement. Here is the whole sample project: https://github.com/neville-nazerane/httpclient-refresh/

Comment: Thank you! I'm going to do some tests. :-)

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use [IdentityModel](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/1_client_credentials.html#creating-the-client) with Keycloak?